# Grid not stacking properly when reaching small size

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Straight to the point...

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <title>Document</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="galary.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.usebootstrap.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">

  <title>image galary</title>
</head>

<body>
  <!-- Nav head bar -->
  <nav class="navbar navbar-default darkblue">
    <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#buttoncollapse" aria-expanded="false">
            <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        </button>
    <div class="container">
      <div class="navbar-header">
        <a href="#" class="navbar-brand"> IMGS</a>
      </div>
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="buttoncollapse">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
          <li> <a href="#"> About us </a> </li>
          <li> <a href="#"> contact </a> </li>
        </ul>
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
          <li> <a href="#">Log in</a> </li>
          <li> <a href="#"> Sign up</a></li>

        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </nav>
  <Div class="container">
    <div class="jumbotron">
      <h1>The Image Gallery</h1>
      <p>A bunch of beautiful images </p>
    </div>
  </Div>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-xs-12 col-sm-6">
        <div class="thumbnail">
          <img src="http://i.imgur.com/qK42fUu.jpg">
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-xs-12 col-sm-6">
        <div class="thumbnail">
          <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1435771112039-1e5b2bcad966?dpr=2&fit=crop&fm=jpg&h=825&q=50&w=1450">
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-xs-12 col-sm-6">
        <div class="thumbnail">
          <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1442406964439-e46ab8eff7c4?dpr=2&fit=crop&fm=jpg&h=825&q=50&w=1450">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-xs-12 col-sm-6">
        <div class="thumbnail">
          <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1439524970634-649c37a69e5c?ixlib=rb-0.3.5&q=80&fm=jpg&crop=entropy&w=1450&h=825&fit=crop&s=bfda9916c885869b43b70738693428d9">
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-xs-12 col-sm-6">
        <div class="thumbnail">
          <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1444090542259-0af8fa96557e?dpr=2&fit=crop&fm=jpg&h=825&q=50&w=1450">
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-xs-12 col-sm-6">
        <div class="thumbnail">
          <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1434543177303-ef2cc7707e0d?dpr=2&fit=crop&fm=jpg&h=825&q=50&w=1450">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-xs-12 col-sm-6">
        <div class="thumbnail">
          <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1436262513933-a0b06755c784?dpr=2&fit=crop&fm=jpg&h=825&q=50&w=1450">
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-xs-12 col-sm-6">
        <div class="thumbnail">
          <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1439396087961-98bc12c21176?dpr=2&fit=crop&fm=jpg&h=825&q=50&w=1450">
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-xs-12 col-sm-6">
        <div class="thumbnail">
          <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1439694458393-78ecf14da7f9?dpr=2&fit=crop&fm=jpg&h=825&q=50&w=1456">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.js" integrity="sha256-WpOohJOqMqqyKL9FccASB9O0KwACQJpFTUBLTYOVvVU=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.usebootstrap.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

In the code above every row has 3 pictures and each row I have implemented the div class "row" however when reaching the small size each row does not take 6 columns. The first row has two pictures of 6 columns, however, the second row has one picture of 6 columns.  This happens repeatedly with the 3rd row having 2 pictures of 6 columns and the 4th row have 1 picture of 6 columns.

However, when taking away the row class for each row it works perfectly fine??

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js">
<script src="https://cdn.usebootstrap.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script></script><link href="https://cdn.usebootstrap.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-xs-12 col-sm-6">
      <div class="thumbnail">
        <img src="http://i.imgur.com/qK42fUu.jpg">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-xs-12 col-sm-6">
      <div class="thumbnail">
        <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1435771112039-1e5b2bcad966?dpr=2&fit=crop&fm=jpg&h=825&q=50&w=1450">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-xs-12 col-sm-6">
      <div class="thumbnail">
        <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1442406964439-e46ab8eff7c4?dpr=2&fit=crop&fm=jpg&h=825&q=50&w=1450">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-xs-12 col-sm-6">
      <div class="thumbnail">
        <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1439524970634-649c37a69e5c?ixlib=rb-0.3.5&q=80&fm=jpg&crop=entropy&w=1450&h=825&fit=crop&s=bfda9916c885869b43b70738693428d9">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-xs-12 col-sm-6">
      <div class="thumbnail">
        <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1444090542259-0af8fa96557e?dpr=2&fit=crop&fm=jpg&h=825&q=50&w=1450">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-xs-12 col-sm-6">
      <div class="thumbnail">
        <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1434543177303-ef2cc7707e0d?dpr=2&fit=crop&fm=jpg&h=825&q=50&w=1450">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-xs-12 col-sm-6">
      <div class="thumbnail">
        <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1436262513933-a0b06755c784?dpr=2&fit=crop&fm=jpg&h=825&q=50&w=1450">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-xs-12 col-sm-6">
      <div class="thumbnail">
        <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1439396087961-98bc12c21176?dpr=2&fit=crop&fm=jpg&h=825&q=50&w=1450">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-xs-12 col-sm-6">
      <div class="thumbnail">
        <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1439694458393-78ecf14da7f9?dpr=2&fit=crop&fm=jpg&h=825&q=50&w=1456">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

If someone could enlighten me that would be great.

Thanks all

Comment: Are you sure your bootstap css is getting loaded ? Because the path you have mentioned in above code block is not correct.

Comment: The code is working properly make sure that you are adding the bootstrap css i.e bootstrap.min.css

Answer (score 0):

Your Bootstrap CSS does not load... Please try below code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-xs-12 col-sm-6">
            <div class="thumbnail">
                <img src="http://i.imgur.com/qK42fUu.jpg">
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-xs-12 col-sm-6">
            <div class="thumbnail">
                <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1435771112039-1e5b2bcad966?dpr=2&fit=crop&fm=jpg&h=825&q=50&w=1450">
            </div>
        </div>


        <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-xs-12 col-sm-6">
                <div class="thumbnail">
                    <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1442406964439-e46ab8eff7c4?dpr=2&fit=crop&fm=jpg&h=825&q=50&w=1450">
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-xs-12 col-sm-6">
                <div class="thumbnail">
                    <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1439524970634-649c37a69e5c?ixlib=rb-0.3.5&q=80&fm=jpg&crop=entropy&w=1450&h=825&fit=crop&s=bfda9916c885869b43b70738693428d9">
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-xs-12 col-sm-6">
                <div class="thumbnail">
                    <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1444090542259-0af8fa96557e?dpr=2&fit=crop&fm=jpg&h=825&q=50&w=1450">
                </div>
            </div>


            <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-xs-12 col-sm-6">
                    <div class="thumbnail">
                        <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1434543177303-ef2cc7707e0d?dpr=2&fit=crop&fm=jpg&h=825&q=50&w=1450">
                    </div>
                </div>

            <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-xs-12 col-sm-6">
                <div class="thumbnail">
                    <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1436262513933-a0b06755c784?dpr=2&fit=crop&fm=jpg&h=825&q=50&w=1450">
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-xs-12 col-sm-6">
                <div class="thumbnail">
                    <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1439396087961-98bc12c21176?dpr=2&fit=crop&fm=jpg&h=825&q=50&w=1450">
                </div>
            </div>


            <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-xs-12 col-sm-6">
                    <div class="thumbnail">
                        <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1439694458393-78ecf14da7f9?dpr=2&fit=crop&fm=jpg&h=825&q=50&w=1456">
                    </div>
                </div>
    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your Bootstrap CSS with this CSS

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
```